# Using onchange for a fetch field

Tags: javascript

I have this code that should return a mileage value from a piece of equipment when the bus is selected. The problem is that the mileage never changes because you really do not click on it. then the wrong mileage is sent to the table, whatever mileage was here before. 
Here is my language

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label style="padding-top:6px;">LTDMileage:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input name="LTDmileage" type="text" class="form-control" id="LTDmileage" onBlur="runTotal(this.form)"
               value="<?php echo $LTDmileage;?>" readonly/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is JS ? ?

Comment: It makes no sense to have `onblur` on a hidden input, since the user can't select it. You need to update that field when the user enters something in the text input.

Comment: That is the issue, we need the mileage to come over and populate the field, without the user having to tab. The forget to tab and just use the mouse and the fetch never comes over